# Display configurable product in a matrix table

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, template, simple-product, products-view

Hi I am creating a magento website for a Timber company that sell their timber based on the section (width x height) and the length. The client wants the products to appear in a matrix table as opposed to the usual set of 2 drop down boxes.

Here is an image to show what I mean.
[image]

Does anyone know of an extension or could anyone put me on the right path as to where I would go to try and achieve this look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently we were looking for something similar when we were making Magento website for a client that sells snap hooks and quick links in larger quantities, so he needed to display configurable products  in a table and allow customers to add larger quantities to cart at once.

Somehow we've stumbled upon the developers from Extensions Mall that were developing a frontend matrix for configurable products at the time, so they offered to give us the module to test it for free.

It this one: https://www.extensionsmall.com/wholesale-add-to-cart-grid.html , and it is pretty good. It shows the price and the quantity available for the each simple product associated. It also displays a message when a certain simple product is out of stock, or not available at all.

It doesn't support swatches out-of-the-box, but the developers were very helpful in making it work with swatches as well. That's one of the reasons why I highly recommend it.

Comment: Thanks!!! That's exactly what I was after. The client has now opted for a simply double drop down but it's worth knowing this for the future. :)

Comment: I've had a small issue with said extension, but as it turned out, it was that we had a really poorly coded theme. However, A. Taylor, this saved a day! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are various extensions for it out there. Just google for something like `magento configurable product matrix`. Possible extensions that fit your needs:

- [Auguria ProductMatrix](http://www.auguria.com/magento/auguria-productmatrix.html) (free)
- [Webguys Configurable Matrix](http://www.webguys.de/magento-extensions-module/configurable-matrix-display-configurable-products-as-table/)
- [Best4Mage Easy Configurable Product Matrix](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/easy-configurable-product-matrix.html)
- [Aitoc Product Matrix](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-matrix.html)

I did not use any of them yet, so I cannot give a detailed review, sorry.

Comment: Ha how did I not find any of them in my Google searches!?!? The Best4Mage company have a slightly different one which is exactly what I am after:

http://www.best4mage.com/configurable-products-frontend-matrix.html

Cheers for the links